# Spark DataGrid on mobile application handle scroll and selection item

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, datagrid, event-handling, flex-spark

I have a spark datagrid on a mobile application, I set the

`interactionMode="touch"`

and the dataGrid scrolling is good, I got some problems adding a `selectionChange` eventListener to it, because scrolling the dataGrid will automatically change the selection and instead simply scrolling it, the function binded will start...

How can I add the touch dalay before select the index, so if I scroll the grid the selection won't change, and it change only if I press the item without scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using a workaround....

Instead adding the `selectionChange` eventListener, I used the `mouseUp` and `mouseDown` to check the time between click and release, and if the release time is less than click plus some dalay, I return the selection otherwise not...

```
<s:DataGrid id="grigliaData"
   sortableColumns="false"
   rowHeight="100"
   interactionMode="touch"
   mouseDown="grigliaData_mouseDownHandler(event)"
   mouseUp="grigliaData_mouseUpHandler(event)"
   top="230" left="5" right="5" bottom="50"
   dataProvider="{listaEventi}" width="100%" height="100%"> 

  //AS Code 
        private var _lastClickEvent:int;
        protected function grigliaData_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _lastClickEvent = getTimer();
        }

        protected function grigliaData_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (getTimer() < _lastClickEvent + 200) // 200 = Dalay
            {
                               // return selectedIndex
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
I also added the check on mouseX and mouseY position, now the grid dispatch the selectionChange if the time before release and the change of position is less that the default dalay (time/pixel)...

Comment: It works, except when clicking on a column header in a datagrid where sort is enabled. To fix this, I used gridMouseDown and gridMouseUp instead of mouseDown and mouseUp.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I had the same problem afterward... and I solved changing the if in mouseUpHandler and adding the selectedIndex > -1 and != null :) :)